mat-sidenav with side doesn't appear side-by-side with the main content
I have this example HTML:
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav class="side-bar-left" mode="side" [opened]="isLeftPanelOpened" position="start" *ngIf="!isPreviewMode">
     ==== some component  ====
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav class="side-bar-right" mode="side" [opened]="(rightPaneState$ |async) != RightPanelState.Hidden"
                 position="end" *ngIf="!isPreviewMode">
      ==== some component  ====
    </mat-sidenav>

</mat-sidenav-content>

The side-bar-left appears side-by-side with the main content, while the side-bar-right goes over the main content and hides it.
Here is my CSS for these classes:
.side-bar-left {
  border-left: 2px solid;
}

.side-bar-right {
  border-right: 2px solid;
}

This issue does not appear to be a CSS problem.

please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and update on the question!
